# Aptitude installs automatically certain packages

Tags: server, aptitude, nagios3

I removed Nagios with `sudo apt-get remove --purge nagios3-core nagios3-common` and `sudo apt-get autoremove` but when I use Aptitude to install something else, It automatically installs Nagios again.

How do I prevent this from happening?

The output of both commands:

```
root@landerghekiere:~/airtime-2.2.0/install_full/ubuntu# apt-get remove --purge nagios3-core nagios3-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package nagios3-common is not installed, so not removed
Package nagios3-core is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@landerghekiere:~/airtime-2.2.0/install_full/ubuntu# apt-get autoremove --purge
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@landerghekiere:~/airtime-2.2.0/install_full/ubuntu#
```

Comment: Paste the output as I explained on the answer, please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
sudo apt-get purge nagios-agent
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

This will remove Nagios and its configuration files, and then it will remove the packages you won't need again after uninstalling Nagios, e.g. its dependences.

If the problem is still here, try to paste the output of those commands in your original question. Remember to select the output and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to mark it as code.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1552085/